# Trying to wrap child elements on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm doing a form helper to react-native, I also want to implement a feature called *namespace* to the forms to get a modular result.

An example:

```
return(
    <Form
        ref="configForm"
    >
        <Form.TextInput
            name="firstName"
        />
        <Form.TextInput
            name="lastName"
        />
        <Form.Namespace name="address">
            <Form.TextInput
                name="city"
            />
            <Form.TextInput
                name="address"
            />
            <Form.TextInput
                name="zip"
            />
        </Form.Namespace>
    </Form>
);
```

In this case the final result must be:

```
{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Tompson',
    address: {
        city: 'New York',
        address: '3th Av 231',
        zip: '32132'
    }
}
```

To get fields values I map recursively the children of FormNamespace, and I clone the elements that own the property *isFormValue* (this property is owned by elements that provide values to Form, which are FormNamespace and FormField):

```
wrapChildren(child) {

    if (!child) {
        return child;
    }

    if (Array.isArray(child)) {
        return child.map((c) => this.wrapChildren(c));
    }

    if (child.type.isFormValue) {
        let ref = child.ref || child.props.name;
        child = React.cloneElement(child, {
            ref: ref,
            style: {borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red'}, // for debug
            onUpdateValue: this.handleFieldChange.bind(this, ref),
        });
    }

    if (child.props.children && !child.type.isFormStopableWrapper) {
        child.props.children = this.wrapChildren(child.props.children);
    }

    return child;
}

render() {
    let childs = this.wrapChildren(this.props.children);
    debugger;

    return(
        <View style={this.props.style}>
            {childs}
        </View>
    );
};
```

All logic is in FormNamespace component, in fact, the Form component only renders a FormNamespace:

```
render() {
    return(
        <Namespace
            ref="formData"
            name="mainNamespace"
            style={[styles.form, this.props.style]}
            onUpdateValue={(data) => this._handleUpdateData(data)}
        >
            {this.props.children}
        </Namespace>
    );
};
```

The Form component works correctly on the first depth, but when must to clone the FormNamespace element, by some issue it does not work as it should.

Debugging, I checked the *React.cloneElement* is applied to the FormNamespace but in the final render the FormNamespace never is referenced (nor the border  style is applied), unlike the FormField that works well.

I don't know what is wrong here, the final FormNamespace rendered has not define the *onUpdateValue* prop. The objective is the FormNamespace be taken like a simple value provider to Form (like fields components) and this manage theirs own children.

The complete component code are here:

- **FormNamespace**: https://paste.kde.org/pyz5gdsgb
- **Form**: https://paste.kde.org/p4kmc2k9j